# Detect CMake build target in CMakeLists.txt?

Tags: cmake

In CMake script `CMakeLists.txt`, how to detect the current build target, like the parameter passed to cmake command via `-A` option? There is variable `WIN32` to detect Windows, but still not the parameter for `-A` option, like `-A X64`.

```
if (WIN32)
    #do something
endif (WIN32)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The platform name that is provided with the `-A` flag is accessible in the `CMakeLists.txt` file via the [`CMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.14/variable/CMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM.html) variable.

Regarding your wording, let me note that there is no such thing like "current build target" in CMake. Rather, the `CMakeLists.txt` file defines, which targets will be available in the generated Makefile (e.g. via `add_executable` or `add_library`) that is created by CMake. CMake itself does not perform builds for specific targets. Which target gets build depends on how you execute the generated Makefile, e.g. `make <targetname>`.